# remapping NameID in service provider to Alias attribute from office365 identity provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am setting up wso2 between office365 and a help desk app that uses SAML 2 for auth. the app expect username in NameID.wso2is identity providers sends guid-like id in the NameID field instead of the alias field which i need in my app.

I already did all the steps from this doc https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-office365/blob/v1.0.4/docs/config.md in addition to defining an Alias claim and then  in service provider added a custom mapping for NameID to alias nad specified subject uri to NameID claim

```
    <saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">0cccccc-444444-45553-1111-92387492387@23423423-sdfs-3333-5555-222222222</saml2:NameID>


    <saml2:AttributeStatement>

        <saml2:Attribute Name="Alias"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                         >
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >j.smith</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
        <saml2:Attribute Name="DisplayName"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                         >
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >John Smith</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>

        <saml2:Attribute Name="Id"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                         >
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >0cccccc-444444-45553-1111-92387492387@23423423-sdfs-3333-5555-222222222</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
        <saml2:Attribute Name="@odata.context"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                         >
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
        <saml2:Attribute Name="EmailAddress"
                         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                         >
            <saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                  xsi:type="xs:string"
                                  >a@b.com</saml2:AttributeValue>
        </saml2:Attribute>
    </saml2:AttributeStatement>
</saml2:Assertion>
```

I need NameID to be NameID to be j.smith from alias attribute

j.smith

Answer (score 0):

Just select the required claim for the `Subject Claim URI` in the service provider claim configurations. Subject Claim URI defines the authenticated user identifier which will return with the authentication response to the service provider. This will be returned as the `NameID` in the SAML response.

You can refer this document for more info on [service provider claim configuration](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider).